# when a file is generated by an executable, what is the file's user and group on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have an executable with user as root and group as ddd

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root ddd 30050496 Jan  1  2021 exed
```

exed will use fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0664); and write(fd, buff, size); to write a file to the hard disk. There is no place to change the group of the filename in the source code.

But I found after running the exed, the filename has fff as group. How did this happen? Should the file's group be ddd?

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root fff  11236167 Nov 13 04:28 filename
```

Comment: Look at the directory (e.g. `ls -al .`) it is probably set `drwxrws---  root fff` where there is no world write permission and it is setgid `fff`. (or your default group is `fff`)

Comment: When you run a program, it typically runs with your ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file's owner will be the effective UID of the process that creates it, and the group will be the effective GID of the process.

The exception is if the directory where the file is created has the `setgid` permission bit set. Then the group will be the group of the directory.